# Snowflake reader account, add SSO

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aad-b2c

Is it possible to add for example azure aadb2c for Snowflake reader account ? There is no real documentation about it.

For the regular account you can do that, but for reader there is really no info about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the Snowflake Reader account is used by a non-Snowflake customer to consume the database shared by the Provider.

The operation such as Okta SSO configuration is the same as the regular account.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! I did set up Okta on the reader accounts and can confirm it works! The steps are exactly the same as a normal account.

Everything in the snowflake setup needs to be done by the consumer account admin role (the reader account owner).